# C++: Checking if user input is one of the characters A, W, or D

Tags: python, c++, validation, loops, conditional-statements

In Python I can do:

```
char_choice = input("What is your character choice? Please enter A, W or   D.")
while char_choice.lower() not in ["a", "w", "d"]:
    char_choice = input("You entered an incorrect character. Please try 
    again:")
```

Is there a way I can repeat line 2 in C++? I have tried the follow in many ways, yet it doesn't work, so I know I am doing something wrong:

```
    char classificationCode;
    cin >> classificationCode;
    while (classificationCode != "b" || classificationCode != "B" ||     classificationCode != "d" || classificationCode != "D" || classificationCode != "w" || classificationCode != "W");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking a char against a string, have you tried

```
classificationCode != 'b'
```

Comment: Indeed. Otherwise you'll be checking the address of the string "b" against the integer value equivalent of the char 'b'

Comment: @RichardGreen Yup, no idea how many times I've spent an hour tracking a bug only to find it was a string not a char.

Comment: Although it's true and important to check against a char and not a string, in the while loop one of those answers will always be True, therefore it will be repeating forever

Comment: @Maor I didn't check his whole loop, I was just pointing out the primary issue which was he was comparing a char to a string.

Comment: This definitely helped. I have to watch out for those double and single quotes haha...

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to Python would be (in C++11):

```
std::unordered_set<char> valid = {'a', 'w', 'd'};
while (!valid.count(tolower(classificationCode))) {
    cout << prompt;
    cin << classificationCode;
}
```

Although there's nothing wrong with putting that logic in a function and just using a `switch`:

```
while (!isValidClassification(classificationCode)) {
    cout << prompt;
    cin >> classificationCode;
}

bool isValidClassification(char code) {
    switch (tolower(code)) {
    case 'a':
    case 'w':
    case 'd':
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}
```

In C++03, there's no `unordered_set` or list-initialization, so you'd have to declare valid like:

```
std::set<char> valid;
valid.insert('a');
valid.insert('w');
valid.insert('d');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can transform your `classificationCode` character to lowercase letters with `tolower()`:

```
char lowerCode = tolower(classificationCode);
```

Note that you need to include the "ctype.h" header file first!

After that, you should get your while condition right. I guess you're doing this inside of a [do-while loop](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson3.html). If you want to make sure that the user enters either "b", "d" or "w", you need to use the logical AND (`&&`). Your condition at the end should then be:

```
// ...
while (lowerCode != 'b' && lowerCode != 'd' && lowerCode != 'w')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the `||` to `&&`, or you could try 
`while (!(classificationCode == 'b' || classificationCode == 'B' || ...))`
don't forget change `""` to `''`, because classificationCode's type is char. 
if you want to get lower, try std::ctype::tolower(), include

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if sequence of characters contains character you can use that code:

```
(std::string("awd").find(std::tolower(ch)) != std::string::npos)
```

Of course there are many ways how to achieve this: use vector instead of string, use C++11 `<locale>` instead of ctype from C, etc.

Comment: He's not checking if a sequence contains a char, he's just trying to check one char against another, so a normal != should work fine.

Comment: @DylanLawrence but this is how `in` in Python works. Also it is Pythonic way to avoid multiple `!=`.

Comment: Ah, I see... I was reading your code backwards. This is indeed how Python does it, but for someone learning C++, it may not be the best choice.

Comment: @DylanLawrence, that is essense of C++ :). In Python there is one "Pythonic" way to do that, and some others that are recommended to avoid. In C++ you can do it C way with `!= 'ch'` or switch (see below) or jump table, in Python way like I advise or even worse - generate conditions with Template MetaProgramming.

Comment: "Template MetaProgramming" Be gone evil demon!